# how do i offset all the charts in the same worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Currently, all my charts are cramped together in the same spot in the same worksheet after running my code. So to view them i have to manually drag and move them to another spot. So is there a way such that i can place all the charts in a orderly manner as shown in expected output? If it is really impossible to do something like this, i am ok with offsetting the graph for every 20 cells even though it is abit inconvenient for viewing but still i attempted to do it but fail to make it happen when i include code with current output with the offsetting code.

Current output(looks like there is 1 chart but all the charts are in the same spot)

[image]

Below is the code for my current output

```
Sub plotgraphs()

'Call meangraph
Call sigmagraph

End Sub
Private Sub sigmagraph()
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Cht As chart, co As Shape
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngX As Range, rngY As Range

    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    Set rngDB = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set rngX = rngDB.Columns(1)
    Set rngY = rngDB.Columns(4)

    Do While Application.CountA(rngY) > 0

        Set co = Worksheets("meangraphs").Shapes.AddChart
        Set Cht = co.chart

        With Cht
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            'remove any data which might have been
            '  picked up when adding the chart
            Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
            Loop
            'add the data
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
                .XValues = rngX.Value
                .Values = rngY.Value
            End With
            'formatting...
            With Cht.Axes(xlValue)
                .MinimumScale = 0
                .MaximumScale = 0.5
                .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"
            End With
            Cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            Cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        End With

        Set rngY = rngY.Offset(0, 2) 'next y values

    Loop
```

Code for offsetting chart for every 20 cells (fail to make it happen)

```
 Dim OutSht As Worksheet
'
   Dim PlaceInRange As Range

    Set OutSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sigmagraphs") '<~~ Output sheet
   Set PlaceInRange = OutSht.Range("B2:J21")        '<~~ Output location
'


'    To place charts at a distance between them
    For Each chart In Sheets("sigmagraphs").ChartObjects
'        OutSht.Paste PlaceInRange
'        Code below changes the range itself to something 20 rows below
        Set PlaceInRange = PlaceInRange.Offset(20, 0)
   Next chart
```

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `.Left` and `.Top` properties of the Shape containing the Chart.

For example, a macro that would setup your charts into a 2-column grid would look like this:

```
Sub SetupChartsIntoGrid()

    Const TopAnchor As Long = 50
    Const LeftAnchor As Long = 50
    Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 10
    Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 10
    Const ChartHeight As Long = 211
    Const ChartWidth As Long = 360

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoChart Then
            Dim Counter As Long
            Counter = Counter + 1
            With shp
                .Top = TopAnchor + (WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Counter / 2, 0) - 1) * (VerticalSpacing + ChartHeight)
                .Left = LeftAnchor + ((Counter + 1) Mod 2) * (HorizontalSpacing + ChartWidth)
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```